# Highlight adjacent cell if a cell contains text from a given reference range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a range of reference locations on Sheet 2, column A. I have a list of locations on Sheet 1, column F. I can get the cells in Column F to highlight if they match one of the reference locations with this formula in conditional formatting: `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,F4:F2500)`.

What I want to do is, instead of highlighting the cell that shows the location in column F, I want to highlight the adjacent cell in column G.

I've found ways to do what I already have working and I have found ways to highlight a cell based on another cell's value, but I can't figure out how to connect the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use the exact same formula, just apply it to the cell next to it.

I changed the formula a little, but if you create a new conditional format in G1 and use this formula: `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,F1)` it will compare the value in F1 to the options in Sheet2 column A and if it finds it, it will apply the format to G1. Then apply the formula to the other cells in Sheet1 column G as needed.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! Actually, I had a working formula in place for it all along and didn't realize it. When you pointed out how it should work, I realized that when I had changed the column from F to G for the CF "applies to" it had updated the reference column from A:A to B:B. So, the reason it wasn't working is because there was nothing in B:B to find! D'oh! I feel better though as that's what I THOUGHT should work. I just didn't realize it had changed that bit. Thanks again!